# Symfony 3, DI - Add service to argument

Tags: php, symfony

I have this code

```
services:
  repo.game:
    class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
    factory_service: doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
    factory_method: getRepository
    arguments:
        - AppBundle\Entity\Game

  file.upload.listener:
    class: AppBundle\Listener\FileUploadListener
    arguments: [@repo.game]
    tags:
        - { name: "kernel.event_listener", event: "oneup_uploader.post_upload", method: "onUpload" }
```

This worked fine in <= 2.8, but here in 3.0 I got this error message

> `[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
>   The file "/ext/thing/app/config/services.yml" does not contain valid
>   YAML.`

`[Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException]
The reserved indicator "@" cannot start a plain scalar; you need to quote the scalar at line 14 (near "arguments: [@repo.game]").`

There is nothing else in my `/ext/thing/app/config/services.yml` file

Comment: It was deprecated in 2.8 and removed in 3.0 (https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/Yaml/Inline.php#L239-L245).  Just quote your service like `arguments: ['@repo.game']` and it should pass.

Comment: And for the `double/single quotes` situation... "using single quotes is easier than double quotes IMO: double quotes in Yaml require to escape many chars in the string, while single quotes only need to escape single quotes themselves (by doubling them)" (quoted from https://github.com/symfony/symfony-demo/issues/246#issuecomment-157686459)

Comment: Once your get past the @ issue you will probably get an error about factory_service.  You will want to use factory, http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html

Comment: @Cerad thanks - and yes, you were right ;-) - And now everything works

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Referring to the UPGRADE Guide in the [yaml section](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md#yaml):

> Starting an unquoted string with @, `, |, or > leads to a
>   ParseException.

So try to modify your configuration as follow:

```
 file.upload.listener:
    class: AppBundle\Listener\FileUploadListener
    arguments: ["@repo.game"]
    tags:
        - { name: "kernel.event_listener", event: "oneup_uploader.post_upload", method: "onUpload" }
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks, Im pretty sure I didnt got any deprecation errors in 2.8, and thats why I "thought" I was safe to upgrade.

Comment: Spent an hour staring at my configuration. Thank you! Now reading the rest of the upgrade guide... :)

Answer (score 1):

First error look like the indent, you have 2 indent space and 4 indent in argument and tags, please try test yml online.

Second symfony 3 is strict now. you need add quote in argument service  `[@repo.game]` to `["@repo.game"]`

Answer (score 0):

For now value with special characters have to be wrapped with single quotes instead of double. It is valid yaml but e.g. it throw many exceptions in phpunit run for symfony