# symfony3 configuration with yaml

Tags: symfony, service, yaml, config, symfony-guard

I am using Guard as new authentification system.
I registered a new service like this:

```
app.form_login_authenticator:
    class: AppBundle\Security\FormLoginAuthenticator
    arguments:
        - @security.password_encoder
        - @router
```

and throws exception:

```
../app/config/config.yml" does not contain valid YAML
```

Anybody could imagine why?

Thanks and Greetings!

Comment: The new yaml processor is a bit stricter.  Use quotes around all strings containing an @ symbol. '@router'

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34069477/symfony-3-di-add-service-to-argument/34070005#34070005

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
app.form_login_authenticator:
    class: AppBundle\Security\FormLoginAuthenticator
    arguments: ["@security.password_encoder","@router"]
```

Comment: Your answer is saying to try something out rather than giving an answer with the explanation as to why the YAML is invalid (as @cerad explained in his comment).  Modify your answer accordingly.